# Deriving a value for Normal Alignment

Tags: opengl

How could I derive a value for how aligned my normals are with a point in space?

For example if my normal faces directly away from point x, it will have a value of 1, whereas if it faces directly towards, it will have a value of 0, or something similar.

Comment: `val = 0.5 - 0.5 * dot(normal, normalize(point - vertex));`

Comment: @jozxyqk this can be an answer.

Comment: Yes thanks @jozxyqk.  Post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `normalize(point - vertex)` gives a direction vector from the vertex to the point
- `dot(normal - normalize(point - vertex))` gives the cosine of the angle between the vertex normal and this direction (1 when the same, -1 when opposite)
- `0.5 - 0.5 * dot(normal, normalize(point - vertex))` inverts and scales this to the 0 to 1 range needed